# WPF valueconverter randomly throws "method or operation is not implemented" after rebuilds

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a value converter in my wpf application that is causing randomly crashing builds. Sometimes the application is working, and changing something completely else and rebuild the project can make the entire application to stop working, throwing

> The method or operation is not implemented

If I remove the value converter the application works perfectly every time. And to get it to work at all I sometimes have to clean and rebuild the solution multiple times (or to remove the converter from the XAML and build then add it back and build again sometimes works as well).

What bothers me the most is that it works sometimes and for no reason at all it just stops working after rebuilds.

This is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Common.Cleanup.Views.CleanupView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Common.Cleanup.Converters"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:IconTypeConverter x:Key="IconConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
        ...
        <TreeView x:Name="CleanItems" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CleanupItemList}" >

            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Margin="0,0,3,0" MinWidth="16" MinHeight="16" Source="{Binding Path=IconType, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}}" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        ...
</Window>
```

and my converter:

```
public class IconTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var iconType = (IconType)value;

        switch (iconType)
        {
            case IconType.View:
                return FileUtility.GetBitmapImage("Shared/Icons/views.ico");
            case IconType.Schedule:
                return FileUtility.GetBitmapImage("Shared/Icons/schedules.ico");
            case IconType.Sheet:
                return FileUtility.GetBitmapImage("Shared/Icons/sheets.ico");
            case IconType.Link:
                return FileUtility.GetBitmapImage("Shared/Icons/links.ico");
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // This is not the issue. I've tried to return null without any differene
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'm building the project with a Debug configuration for x64 platform.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Mode=OneWay` in your image binding and things should get better.

Like this:

```
<Image Margin="0,0,3,0" MinWidth="16" MinHeight="16" 
       Source="{Binding Path=IconType, Converter={StaticResource IconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This is because in `ConvertBack` function of your converter, you have asked it to throw exception. So whenever it tries to update source with the changed value of the UI element, the `ConvertBack` function is called and throws the exception you're seeing.

### Edit

I just saw your comment in the `ConvertBack` function. I still suggest that you give my answer a try. Also try returning `NotSupportedException` instead of returning `NotImplementedException` or null and see if the error message changes.

Comment: Why? OP seems to think that the ConvertBack method is not at cause here.

Comment: @CorentinPane: He didn't say anything like that. Additionally `The method or operation is not implemented` message clearly indicates that `NotImplementedException` is being thrown, which is not thrown by the Framework components generally.

Comment: He wrote `// This is not the issue. I've tried to return null without any differene` in the `ConvertBack` method.

Comment: @CorentinPane: I missed that comment. I'm still positive that he should give this answer a try. There is every reason for me to believe that it is exactly that line of code that's causing the specified exception.

Comment: Thank you. But both your suggestions seems to change nothing about the issue. =( It's still randomly throwing the same error (`The method or operation is not implemented`) and now there are no traces left of any other NotImplementedExceptions!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the obj and bin folders, and cleaning the solution?

Comment: @Keithernet thanks but that did not help either... I really can't understand it! It feels like it should be something other than the code, maybe there are something wrong with the project setup or Visual Studio 2019 or whatever.